# How can I troubleshoot my dysfunctional Trigger-Ready Flow?

Tags: trigger, debugging, flow

Currently following the "Calculate Discounts on Opportunities" in the "[Cloud Flow Designer Workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_flow/workbook_flow.pdf)"  (starts on page 26.)

I'm 99% positive that I've followed all the instructions exactly.

But when I test the flow, the "Discounted_Percentage__c" field never updates, but rather remains blank.

I've tried adding a second (default-false checkbox) field called "Discount Flow has Completed", which should set to the Global constant true, regardless of any decision made.  But this remains false.

Any ideas how I can diagnose and resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by adding some Screen Interfaces from the Palette.

I used the screens to display my variables' values as Display Text.

Turns out the input variables were not getting in.

Further investigation revealed that UNLIKE MOST OF SFDC, these variables are case sensitive.  (E.g. "AccountId" is not the same as "AccountID".)